# Having a dynamic table to choose from in pyodbc to insert the values

Tags: python, database, ms-access, sql-insert, pyodbc

I have the following code on python with pyodbc:

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO table(F1,F2,F3)
                        VALUES(?,?,?)
                        ''',

                        (no,gpu,price)
                        )

                    cursor.commit()
```

Is there any way to make the table name as a variable? For example to be able to define which table will be used to insert the values. I have tried those 2 so far

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO %s(F1,F2,F3)
                        VALUES(?,?,?)
                        ''',% table

                        (no,gpu,price)
                        )

                    cursor.commit() 


 cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO ?(F1,F2,F3)
                        VALUES(?,?,?)
                        ''',

                        (table,no,gpu,price)
                        )

                    cursor.commit()
```

i know there might be a security issue in case of SQL injection but i am going to be the only one using the database. Thank you in advance

Comment: In that case, I think you need to format the query using f-strings, like this: `cur.execute(f"select * from {mytable} where ts='{my_date}'")`

Comment: Hey thanks! f strings did the trick!